# How to Convert a Storage file in an array of byte in uwp

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp-xaml

I have to store my document in my sqlite database and for that i am using Storage file to temporary store that file and now i need to convert that Storage file in an array of byte. Is there any way to implement that thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you can get your storage file, the type is `StorageFile`, you can use this method to convert:

```cs
public async Task<byte[]> GetBytesFromFile(StorageFile file)
{
    var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
    await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return bytes;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Working fine ...Thanks